# React navigation: manually change screen with swipe up effect

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, swipe-gesture, react-native-animatable

I have a screen with WebView (react-native-webview) which has scrollable content. If user continues scrolling after reaching the end of WebView, I want to take user to a different screen with a swipe up animation. With WebView's onScroll function property, I am able to determine if the user has reached end of content or not. But I am not able to take user to a different screen with an animation effect.

Since WebView acts different for android and ios platform (you can continue scrolling even after reaching end of content on ios), I had to use PanGestureHandler to identify if the user is performing swipe up action after reaching end of web content. But when I manually try to navigate user to a different screen, I am unable to create swipe up effect similar to one in GIF below.

I am using react-navigation v5 in my app.

I have already tried using react-native-swiper. It does not work well in Android because it internally uses Scrollable and WebView stop scrolling inside a Scrollable component.

I am using custom HTML content here, so replacing WebView is not really a choice. Is there a way to utilize Stack Navigator to create such an effect?

[image: Swipe Up Changing screen]

Thank you.